# configure needs C++14 support but gcc -v = 4.9.3

Tags: gcc, g++, c++14, configure, graph-tool

I am currently in the process of compiling graph-tool v1.13 from the Git version. I have managed to generate the `configure` file from `autogen.sh` but am now running into trouble.

Running `./configure` I receive the message:

```
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++14... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++0x... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++14 language features is required.
```

I have checked `gcc -v` and `g++ -v` and receive the response `gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04)`. To my knowledge this should support C++14 so where am I going wrong? I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Just install a newer version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) perhaps by compiling GCC 5.3 (the latest version of GCC in febr.2016) from its source code.

Comment: Installing GCC 5.x would probably work, agreed, but I wonder why the current version does not work when it looks to me like it should...

Comment: Because GCC 4.9 was released in april 2014 before the C++14 standard finalization... (so the support for a not yet released standard is experimental). You should upgrade to GCC 5

Comment: I have installed them using `sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5` but `gcc -v` still returns `gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04)`. What am I missing?

Comment: The flag may be `c++1y` or `gnu++1y` for GCC 4.9

Comment: `gcc-5` and `g++-5` may have been installed under exactly those names, leaving your system compiler GCC 4.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try perhaps

```
./configure CXX='g++-5'
```

after having installed some [GCC 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/)

Comment: @P-M: `configure` would mean "the command `configure` found in the command path" -- which does not exist, leading to the error message you mentioned. `./configure` means "the command `configure` *in the current directory*"...

Answer (score 2):

gcc 4.9.3 supports C++14, but the correct compiler flag is '-std=c++14'